# WPF Dispatcher Thread- Using lambda expression and throw to dispatch exception to UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, lambda, throw

```
try
{
    string s = null;
    s.PadLeft(10);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // send exception to UI Thread so it can be handled by our global exception 
    // handler
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, 
        new Action<Exception>(e => { throw ex; }), ex);
}
```

As you can see, 'throw ex' will truncate the stacktrace, I would like to use `throw` instead of `throw ex` but I get:

> A throw statement with no arguments is not allowed outside of a catch clause.

How can I use lambda expression to throw the exception without truncating stacktrace?

Comment: I believe this is because throw is a statement not an expression, so you've to raise a new exception and pass existing one as inner, as adviced by Botz below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just create a new Exception with the old exception as InnerException?

```
e => throw new WhateverException("your message", ex);
```

That preserves the original stacktrace.